# What causes record pages to not show up for users?

Tags: lightning-experience

I created a new contact record page for my users using the page editor and activated it as the org default. None of the changes I've made (adding lightning components like single related lists) show for any user but me.

What could be causing this issue? It's crucial that I be able to create record pages for my users.

Comment: What are they seeing instead? How long has it been since you made the page the default (Lightning caches aggressively, and users often see old config for a while after a change has been made).

Comment: They _were_ seeing a generic Main Content with Right Sidebar, where main content was tabs with details, related, and activity and right sidebar just a chatter/activity. I had put a related list for org affiliations in the right side bar (we're a nonprofit) and that was what wasn't showing up. Now that I come back to it after the weekend I find that my changes are happening immediately! May have something to do with our subdomain changing?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been having this issue as well (in Spring '19) when just setting the Lightning record page as the org default.  Not sure if this is an actual Salesforce bug or some other nuance.

In the meantime, try activating the page for specific apps and profiles, rather than just the org default and it should work as expected.